# Night train Fukuoka - Tokyo

Tags: trains, japan, night-transport

I have three free days in Japan. Google maps says a train ride from Fukuoka to Tokyo takes more than ten hours which is basically an entire day. To save time, I was wondering whether there a night/sleeper train between Fukuoka and Tokyo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Google maps says a train ride from Fukuoka to Tokio takes more than ten hours which is basically an entire day.

That doesn't seem to be correct. There are many direct Nozomi trains from Fukuoka to Tokyo that take about 5 hours one way. If you hop on the train in Hakata at 7.15am in the morning you are in Tokyo at 12:15 and just in time for lunch. Cost is about JPY27000 or $US188

Flying would in almost all cases be cheaper and faster.

[Apparently Japan has eliminated most sleeper trains](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2356.html), simply because flying is cheaper and faster. There is apparently only one left, and if you are so inclined you can actually take it. Below is an example for Oct 4. However it's about three times as expensive as a one-way flight.

Since Hyperdia got discontinued. searching Japan train schedules has been a pain in the neck. [A workable alternative appears to be here](https://roote.ekispert.net/en). Buying tickets is also a pain in the neck. Online tickets are very sparse and they need to be shipped to you somehow.

[image]

Comment: It's expensive because the sleeper is actually going to a different island (Shikoku), so you're paying for the sleeper to around halfway at Himeji plus a separate bullet train (Shinkansen) from Himeji to Fukuoka.

Comment: Direct route on the Nozomi is just about the same price.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying that if you take the sleeper to its destination, it's much cheaper (about half price) compared to the Shinkansen, and saves on a night's accommodation too.

Answer (score 3):

The only scheduled sleeper trains in Japan are the Sunrise Izumo and Sunrise Seto, neither of which travel to Fukuoka.

The best and fastest way is, of course, to fly (either to Haneda, or to Narita on the low-cost Peach Aviation, which can be erally cheap).

The second most popular is probably to take the Shinkansen bullet train, but that takes like 5 hours and the last train departs Hakata at 18:59, arriving in Tokyo almost midnight, at 23:45; it's quite expensive too, and often more expensive than flying.

The cheapest way is to take an overnight bus, but that means upwards of 12 hours in a minimally reclinable seat, so I would rather not try that.